# Adding text from a file in the middle of a url

Tags: linux, bash, curl, hyperlink

I have a text in a file `id.txt` and I want to add the contents of the file to a curl link:

```
curl localhost:1337/id.txt/map/maze-of-doom?type=csv
```

In a bash script. I don't want it to be added to the end or beginning. I want it to be added in the place where id.txt is written in the code.

Answer (score 0):

To replace the first occurrence of a pattern with a given string, use ${parameter/pattern/string}:

So, if I've a file **id.txt** that contains *"www.foo.bar"*

```
idTxt=$(cat id.txt)
baseUrl="localhost:1337/id.txt/map/maze-of-doom?type=csv"
url=${baseUrl/id.txt/$idTxt}
echo $url
```

the last echo will show:

```
localhost:1337/www.foo.bar/map/maze-of-doom?type=csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the command Substitution sequence: `$(...)` for example

```
curl localhost:1337/$(cat id.txt)/map/maze-of-doom?type=csv
```

Comment: Standard warnings and disclaimers apply, this is point-of-execution command injection, #10 entry on the 2020 CWE: http://cwe.mitre.org/top25/archive/2020/2020_cwe_top25.html Such arrangements should be confined to the inner sanctums of total trust, behind as many layers of security as possible.  If whatever is in that catted file comes from a user, then quoting yoda, owned your box is.  Given that `id.txt` sounds like user-generated content, you're asking for trouble.  everything after a semicolon in that file will be run as a command.  watchout for user id's such as `; rm -rf /`